# Fix or disable dead Telegram notifications from another workspace

Tags: workspaces, notification, mate, telegram

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

When I receive a message in Telegram, I get a popup notification at the bottom right of the screen. Normally, I can click a 'close' box in the corner of the popup to dismiss it, or click anywhere else on the notification to go to the conversation.

However, when I'm in a different workspace to the one where Telegram is open, the notification still pops up, only it's no longer clickable - it's dead, and sometimes gets in the way of what I'm doing:

[image]

I can see that I've got Telegram messages from any workspace by looking in at the top panel, where the number of new messages displays on the Telegram icon, so I don't *urgently* need the popup.

[image]

So I would like to change the behaviour of the popup notification so that it either works properly in all workspaces (which would probably require allowing the application to change workspaces), **or** appears only on the workspace where Telegram is open.

Comment: What you described "However, when I'm in a different workspace to the one where Telegram is open, the notification still pops up, only it's no longer clickable - it's dead" is not the case in my test. I can see the close mark on all notification

Comment: maybe it's been fixed @AnwarShah since I wrote my question... let me test it :)

Comment: Also, Is it ok if you don't get the pop up notification at all? It seems, these pop ups are managed by Telegram instead of MATE

Comment: aha! the popups are dismissable but I can't switch to the workspace by clicking them. That's bearable. Also I can't switch to the workspace by clicking the indicator panel icon, but that's OK too... I guess this is no repro

Comment: For Future readers, You can disable the pop up notification by going to the Settings -> Notification -> Desktop Notification. That will disable it but you'll get an indicator of new messages in panel icon.